# Do we need multiple multi-monitor tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Inspired by a recent [MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355598/can-we-merge-the-four-multiple-monitors-tags), I looked here and found two possibly-overlapping tags:

- [dual-monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor)
- [multi-monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-monitor)

Should we merge them and make dual-monitor a synonym of multi-monitor?

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Comment: Makes sense to me as well.

Comment: I'll carry on with the tagging efforts, then. I assume we need to ping a moderator to create the synonym?

Comment: Also: dualhead (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dualhead?sort=newest)